# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to perform Custom displayFormat using Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have these two fields FromDate and ToDate

```
[Required] 
[MaxLength(8)]
[MinLength(8)]
public string FromDate { get; set; }

[Required] 
[MaxLength(8)]
[MinLength(8)]
public string ToDate { get; set; }
```

I want to display to the user in the Swagger Web API that the format for **FromDate** and **ToDate** should be like this yyyyMMdd e.g. 20220920 using Data Annotation

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why aren't you using `DateTime` instead of `String`?

Comment: "Display format" is the wrong idea. An API is about delivering data. Dates have to be delivered as string-like values, but leave that up to the framework to handle for you. OpenAPI specifies using [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) formats for temporal values. The consumer of your API should be responsible for converting that to whatever "display format" it requires.

Comment: @Dai -  The requirement for the the project as given is like that. They want the user to enter something like yyyyMMdd   as in 20220715.   Then the conversion is done in .NET Core code and stored procedure

Comment: @madreflection - Noted. But I want the user to know the format from beginning.   The requirement for the the project as given is like that. They want the user to enter something like yyyyMMdd as in 20220715. Then the conversion is done in .NET Core code and stored procedure

Comment: @Ayobamilaye It is your responsibility to push-back against bad requirements.

Comment: Swagger UI is a testing/debugging interface, not a user-facing UI. A proper consumer of the API (e.g. a web application) can take whatever format it wants. It needs to convert the *user input format* to the *wire format* to make the call. You're putting that conversion in the wrong place.